# SignInWithCredentialAsync on iOS causes System.AggregateException

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using the Firebase Unity SDK for authentication with FB and Google.

When trying it out on iOS FB works fine, but whenever I login with Google it works the first time, but when I relaunch the application and try to use the Google login again it causes an internal Firebase error.

Here's the printout I get :

```
SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
-----------------

Encountered a FirebaseException:An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
Valley.DatabaseHandler:<RequestLogin>m__0(Task`1)
System.Threading.Tasks.<ContinueWith>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Task)
System.Threading.Tasks.<ContinueWith>c__AnonStorey2:<>m__0(Task)
System.Threading.Tasks.<ContinueWith>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:<immediateExecutor>m__1(Action)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:RunContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetException(AggregateException)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetException(Exception)
Firebase.Auth.<GetTask>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0()
Firebase.Auth.Future_User:SWIG_CompletionDispatcher(Int32)
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update()
```

My `RequestLogin()` function looks like this :

```c#
public void RequestLogin(string id, string token, bool useId)
{
    Credential credential;
    if (useId)
    {
        credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(id, token);
    }
    else
    {
        credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(token);
    }

    if (credential != null)
    {
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                AggregateException ex = task.Exception as AggregateException;
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    FirebaseException fbEx = null;
                    foreach (Exception e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        fbEx = e as FirebaseException;
                        if (fbEx != null)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError("Encountered a FirebaseException:" + fbEx.Message);
                            fbEx = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
                _user = auth.CurrentUser;
                _gameController.ActivateScene(GameController.Scene.GAME);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm not finding any more details in the exceptions.

Anyone know how to solve this? And why it only happens from the second launch and onwards and not on the first login with Google?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

At times I also get this which might be related:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_Available () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```